# A way to make DropDownListFor with DropDowns inside in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

Let's say i have a class Person which has

```
public string Name {get;set;}

public List<string> ListOfStrings  {get;set;}
```

and i'm trying to bind `List<Person>` to DropDownListFor so it would look like that

Dropdown: 
  - First person
       - First string of the listOfStrings of first person
       - Second string of the listOfStrings of first person
  - Second Person
       - First string of the listOfStrings of second person
       - Second string of the listOfStrings of second person
       - third string of the listOfStrings of second person

etc

Is there a way to make it like that? only the strings in list should be selectable and not name of the person. I'm fine with anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a Razor way of doing this other than a model and a foreach loop, but the HTML you are looking for will be something like this

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Person1">
    <option value="ListOfStrings1">ListOfStrings1</option>
    <option value="ListOfStrings2">ListOfStrings2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Person2">
    <option value="ListOfStrings3">ListOfStrings3</option>
    <option value="ListOfStrings4">ListOfStrings4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Edit: as of MVC 5.2 there actually *is* a way to do this. You can find detailed instructions on how to create this HTML with Razor a little more elegantly than with a foreach loop [here](http://www.kashyapas.com/2014/06/09/html-ldquooptgrouprdquo-support-in-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc-5-2/).

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straight-forward. The only tricky part is selecting all the string values into one big list, while still keyed to a particular person. Thankfully `SelectMany` takes a `resultSelector` param that lets you do exactly that. Then, you just select everything into a list of `SelectListItem`s and specify the `Group` property for each. Razor will then happily take care of generating the appropriate optgroups in the HTML. One thing of note: I think the ability to specify groups didn't come about until MVC 5, though.

```
ViewBag.DropDownOptions = db.People
    .SelectMany(m => m.ListOfStrings, (m, str) => new { Name = m.Name, String = str })
    .Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = m.String,
        Text = m.String,
        Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = m.Name }
    });
```

Then, in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Foo, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownOptions)
```

Comment: It was 5.2 RC - see work item [#1703](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1703)

Comment: @Sam: Cool. Thanks. I really wish the MSDN docs would indicate what version of things like MVC you need. Instead, all you get is that's part of the MVC namespace, so it requires some unspecified version of MVC. Thanks, MS ;).